# How to use media query in react native?

Tags: react-native, sass, media-queries

I have used SCSS in my react native application ,so i want to use media query for mobile devices.

I have used `react-native-sass-transformer` plugin for translate scss into css.

My problem is media queries not getting applied in react native.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `react-native-css-media-query-processor` package, provided by the same author of the `react-native-sass-transformer` package.

GitHub project: [Here](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-media-query-processor)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set it up correctly?

Your App.scss file might look like this:

```css
%blue {
  color: blue;
}
.myClass {
  @extend %blue;
}
.myOtherClass {
  color: red;
}
.my-dashed-class {
  color: green;
}
```

When you import your stylesheet:

```js
import styles from "./App.scss";
```

**Plain React Native:**

```js
<MyElement style={styles.myClass} />

<MyElement style={styles["my-dashed-class"]} />
```

***Config:***

For React Native v0.57 or newer / Expo SDK v31.0.0 or newer
Add this to `metro.config.js` in your project's root (create the file if it does not exist already):

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-sass-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "scss", "sass"]
    }
  };
})();
```